# Realm Studio syntax filtered list of results based on linked object

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm, realm-studio

What is the proper way to query in Realm Studio and retrieve a list of objects that satisfy one condition as well as satisfying the state of linked records

Example

ObjectB {
id: STRING
included: BOOL
}

ObjectA {
id: STRING
subID: STRING
objBArray: List
}

so what would the query be if I want to get back all ObjectA's that have an subID of "123" and only if one of the elements in objBArray's isIncluded = true

When looking at the ObjectA Table:

subID = "123" and $0.objBArray.isIncluded == true

Comment: You should take a look at subqueries: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/filter-data/#subqueries and https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: The object structure is a little unclear as Realm does not have arrays and what property is linked should be clarified. Can you include your actual object models please?

Comment: @Jay sorry didn't mean Array.. it's a List<ObjectB> and I want to include the results only if the elements in List<ObjectB> has a value of isIncluded

Comment: @Rob, thanks I've been looking at that but wanted to get the Query in Realm Studio working so that I could validate the results there first

Comment: So I found that I can use this in RealmStudio and get the results, HOWEVER I CANNOT can get the NSPredicate in SWIFT to work. I keep getting "Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations" The query string I found that works in Studio is: objectA.subID == 'JJQA4' AND (objBArray.@count > 1) AND objBArray.isIncluded = true

Comment: I would mention again that the question is a bit vague - the title asks about LinkedObjects and there's nothing in the question that is a LinkedObject. You can transverse back through the relationship with LinkingObjects so that may be part of the answer but you should really include the actual Realm Models in your question so we understand the relationship (and what is Linked). You will probably need to include the keyword 'ANY' if you are querying through the graph but that's just guesswork until we see the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I needed to use "AND ANY linkedobjects.Id = nil" it was the combination of AND along with ANY followed by the "array/list" of objects and condition